# Problem converting a JSON to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have a `JSON` that I am trying to convert but I am facing problems. I have pasted below the JSON and the command which I am using. Any help, is appreciated.
Thanks

```
   {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 43, 'features': 1},
 'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'With',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
    'location': [0, 4],
    'lemma': 'with'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [5, 10],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'power',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [11, 16],
    'lemma': 'power'},
   {'text': 'comes',
    'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
    'location': [17, 22],
    'lemma': 'come'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [23, 28],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'responsibility',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [29, 43],
    'lemma': 'responsibility'}],
  'sentences': [{'text': 'With great power comes great responsibility',
    'location': [0, 43]}]},
 'language': 'en'}
```

Code I am using:

```
ot1 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path = ['syntax',['tokens']], meta = ['language', ['usage', 'text_units']])
```

I am getting an error saying KeyError: `text_units`

Comment: I'm getting `KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'text_units' is not always present"`. Passing `errors="ignore"` works for me.

Comment: I did add errors="ignore" but it gave me all NaN while the data contains a value in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ace, I think the problem is the ordering -> you are trying to start from the 3rd level of granularity of your JSON and then add the 2nd level. I don't think it will work with json_normalize (hopefully someone will be able to provide more details).

By now, one possible workaround would be to stop at the 'usage' key and then convert the column to np series :

```
ot1 = pd.json_normalize(a_json, record_path = ['syntax',['tokens']], meta = ['language','usage'])

ot1[['text_units', 'text_characters', 'features']] = ot1.usage.apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Thanks MarcZ, this workaround does the work. Thanks a lot.